# Can oil "boil" in vacuum ? (Is it usable to make absolute (low) pressure measurement ?)

Tags: vacuum, evaporation

In order to measure vacuum absolute pressure, I thought about making a water column barometer, however, water will boil under high vacuum. Can I use oil instead ? On one side, I would expect any liquid to boil at extreme low pressure, but if it was the case, it would be a problem for oil vacuum pumps... ?

Comment: A quick search for “vacuum pump oil” turns up quite a few options. Then you check for vapor pressures.

Comment: You are going to need a VERY tall column of oil.  I would guess that the height of your column of oil would be in the range of 40-45 feet.

Comment: You really need mercury here: it has a very, very low vapour pressure and your column would only need to be 760 mm,

Comment: Well, you both missed the fact that I'm not measuring the atmospheric pressure but vacuum pressure. I Only need a bit more than 1cm for 100 Pa.